# Stuck on Access coding

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a code that adds records from a form to a table, but when the check boxes are selected, it is adding a -1 (true) in the table field. How can I revise my code to have an alternate word added rather than the -1?

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Raw_Audits")

With rs
  .AddNew
  .Fields("Name") = Me.Combo0
  .Fields("COLL") = Me.Check205
  .Fields("COMP") = Me.Check227
  .Fields("UMPD") = Me.Check294
  .Update
  .Close
End With
```

Comment: Add an IF THEN statement to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [If..Then statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)...

For example, replace:

```
.Fields("COLL") = Me.Check205
```

with

```
If Me.Check205 = -1 then
    .Fields("COLL") = "True"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried multiple variations, but none of mine worked, this one worked like a charm though!